# Help to draw an arbitrary surface with in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, technical-drawing

I need help to draw an arbitrary surface in TikZ, in order to represent a manifold. I am trying to make something with shade. I manage to get a rectangular surfcace with corners, shaded color, etc but it does not look as good.

Can anyone give me an example and tell me how I can edit it? I do not need something complicated.

Also, is there a manual specifically mentioning how to draw various stuff for diff. geometry?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The linked question covers "simple" surfaces. Sometimes one needs more complicated surface as known from plot tools. For such advanced surfaces see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31708/draw-a-bivariate-normal-distribution-in-tikz/31713#31713 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99133/creating-bezier-surfaces-using-procedural-graphics/102585#102585

Comment: The answer to [How to draw a 3d curved manifold in tikz](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/80502/3954) can also be useful here.